# Ajax request using Fetch in React

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, fetch

I'm doing an Ajax request in React using Fetch. The request is working fine but I'm getting an error even though I specified a unique key. Here is the warning message:

**Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Table`.**

Any idea why I would be getting this error?

**My code:**

```
let Table = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { 
            accounts: [{
                "product": "Fixed Saver", 
                "interestRate": 2.20,
                "minimumDeposit": 500,
                "interestType": "Fixed"
            }] 
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        fetch('http://localhost/table/json/accounts.json')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({accounts: json})
            });
    },
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <ul className="header clearfix">
                    <li>Product</li>
                    <li>Interest rate</li>
                    <li>Minimum deposit</li>
                    <li>Interest type</li>
                </ul>

                {this.state.accounts.map(account => {
                return (
                    <div className="account clearfix">
                        <div key={account.id}>{account.product}</div>
                        <div>{account.interestRate} %</div>
                        <div>£ {account.minimumDeposit}</div>
                        <div>{account.interestType}</div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })} 
            </div>
        )
    }
});

let App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <Table />
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('table') );
```

**JSON file**

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "product": "Fixed Saver", 
      "interestRate": 2.20,
      "minimumDeposit": 500,
      "interestType": "Fixed"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "product": "Fixed Saver", 
      "interestRate": 1.50,
      "minimumDeposit": 0,
      "interestType": "Tracker"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "product": "Offset Saver", 
      "interestRate": 1.8,
      "minimumDeposit": 1000,
      "interestType": "Fixed"
   }
]
```

**[UPDATED]**

Looks like React doesn't like my unique IDs for some reason. I've added an index to map and it now works:

```
{this.state.accounts.map((account,i) => {
    return (
        <div className="account clearfix" key={i}>
            <div key={account.id}>{account.product}</div>
            <div>{account.interestRate} %</div>
            <div>£ {account.minimumDeposit}</div>
            <div>{account.interestType}</div>
        </div>
    )
})}
```

Also realised that in getInitialState, the array of objects "accounts" is missing the property "id", which is probably the reason why I was having the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component for your account info.

```
const Account = ({ account }) => (
  <div className="account clearfix">
    <div key={account.id}>{account.product}</div>
    <div>{account.interestRate} %</div>
    <div>£ {account.minimumDeposit}</div>
    <div>{account.interestType}</div>
  </div>
);
```

Then map your data array like this:

```
{this.state.accounts.map(account => <Account key={account.id} account={account} />)}
```

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the quick response. Just tried that, still getting the same error though.

Comment: If you inspect the props, do you see that each of those divs has a unique `key` as it should?

Comment: No you are right - the unique key is not being attached for some reason.

Comment: Is it still on the child div, or not present at all?

Comment: Not present at all. But it does console.log out.

Comment: Forgive the question, but you are using the React dev-tools and not the regular DOM inspector, right?

Comment: My bad. The keys are actually showing in React dev-tools.

Comment: Edited answer with alternative approach.

Comment: Still getting the same issue with this approach. How odd.

Comment: Found a way to fix the warning issue. I updated my question.